# Special characters within the code - PHP

Tags: php, xml, utf-8, simplexml

in my code i have to show some element of an object ( a xml file), but the problem i am having is that the names of the elements contain special characters like "é", "à", "è" "ç" etc...

so when i try for example t show :

```
echo $xml->CoordonnéesNum->Téléphone;
```

it doesn't work, so i have to change it to something like this : 
     $xml->Coor->Tel //without the special characters

but i have thousands of xml files in wich these elements are named with these special characters and i cannot change them all manually

i have to mention that im new to php:

so please if you can help to fix this issue that would be wonderful.

Comment: You can use the complex curly syntax: `$xml->{"CoordonnéesNum"}->{"Téléphone"}`

Comment: here is what i tried.  $Org1 = $xml->{'CoordonnéesNum'}->{'Téléphone'}; and it didn't worked :/

Comment: Is your PHP script saved in UTF-8, like the XML file?

Comment: If it's saved as UTF-8 it should work like in the question. If it is not UTF-8, you can use curly brackets: `echo $xml->{"Coordonn\xC30\xA9esNum"}->{"T\xC30\xA9l\xC30\xA9phone"};`

Comment: i used the meta carset to set mypage to utf-8 and its not working, i tried also using the $xml->{"Coordonn\xC30\xA9esNum"}->{"T\xC30\xA9l\xC30\xA9phone"}; and its not working neither !!

Comment: it worked, my php page wasn't saved as utf-8, thank you brothers :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this instead:

```
echo $xml->{"CoordonnéesNum"}->{"Téléphone"};
```

Comment: Hey brad, i tried it but it didn't worked, any other ideas, thank you in advance :)